# Lower case enum Gson

Tags: java, json, gson

I need to output enum values using Gson which due to client limitations need to be in lower case.

For example `CLOSE_FILE` would be `close_file`.

Is there a simple way of doing this? I have looked at making a class which implements `JsonSerializer` but it looks like I would have to manually serialize the whole class (which is quite complex) is this the case?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

If you have control over the `enum` type, annotate its members with `@SerializedName` and give it the appropriate serialized value. For example,

```
enum Action {
    @SerializedName("close_file")
    CLOSE_FILE;
}
```

If you don't have control over the `enum`, provide a custom `TypeAdapter` when creating a `Gson` instance. For example,

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().registerTypeAdapter(Action.class, new TypeAdapter<Action>() {

    @Override
    public void write(JsonWriter out, Action value) throws IOException {
        out.value(value.name().toLowerCase());
    }

    @Override
    public Action read(JsonReader in) throws IOException {
        return Action.valueOf(in.nextString().toUpperCase());
    }
}).create();
```

Comment: Question: The type adapter will rewrite _all_ values to lowercase? I don't see anything specific to enum in the code.

Comment: @frieder The type adapter is registered only for the enum type. It’ll be invoked only when serializing values of that type.

Comment: Oh yeah now I see it - it's registered for the specific `Action` enum. D'oh. :P Is it possible to register for all enum types?

Comment: @friederbluemle `Enum` is the supertype of all enum types. Serializing will probably be easy, you just lowercase `name()`, but deserializing would need a more information about what actual type to deserialize to.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to serialize all enum to lowercase, you can use this code

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().registerTypeHierarchyAdapter(Enum.class, new EnumToLowerCaseJsonConverter()).create();
```

```
public final class EnumToLowerCaseJsonConverter implements JsonSerializer<Enum<?>>, JsonDeserializer<Enum<?>> {
    private static Map<String, Class<? extends Enum<?>>> typesToClass = new HashMap<>();
    
    @Override
    public JsonElement serialize(final Enum<?> src, final Type typeOfSrc,
            final JsonSerializationContext context) {
        if (src == null) {
            return JsonNull.INSTANCE;
        }
        return new JsonPrimitive(src.name().toLowerCase());
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public Enum<?> deserialize(final JsonElement json, final Type typeOfT,
            final JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
        if (json == null || json.isJsonNull()) {
            return null;
        }
        
        if (!json.isJsonPrimitive() || !json.getAsJsonPrimitive().isString()) {
            throw new JsonParseException(
                    "Expecting a String JsonPrimitive, getting " + json.toString());
        }
        
        try {
            final String enumClassName = typeOfT.getTypeName();
            Class<? extends Enum<?>> clazz = typesToClass.get(enumClassName);
            if (clazz == null) {
                clazz = (Class<? extends Enum<?>>) Class.forName(enumClassName);
                typesToClass.put(enumClassName, clazz);
            }
            
            return Enum.valueOf((Class) clazz, json.getAsString().toUpperCase());
        } catch (final ClassNotFoundException e) {
            throw new JsonParseException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An easy to use specific type adapter:

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().registerTypeAdapter(Action.class, new EnumToLowerCaseTypeAdapter<>(Action.class)).create();
```

```
public final class EnumToLowerCaseTypeAdapter<T extends Enum<?>> extends TypeAdapter<T> {
    private final Class<T> clazz;
    
    public EnumToLowerCaseTypeAdapter(final Class<T> clazz) {
        this.clazz = clazz;
    }

    @Override
    public void write(final JsonWriter out, final T value) throws IOException {
        if (value == null) {
            out.nullValue();
        } else {
            out.value(value.name().toLowerCase());
        }
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public T read(final JsonReader in) throws IOException {
        
        switch (in.peek()) {
            case NULL:
                in.nextNull();
                return null;
            default:
                final String value = in.nextString();
                return (T) Enum.valueOf((Class) clazz, value.toUpperCase());
        }
    }
}
```