# Gson Enum serialization

Tags: java, serialization, enums, gson

I'm using `gson` in my java web app to serialize my api models to json objects.
I have succesfuly used its annotations for versioned models, but I'm failing to serialize `Enum` objects.

Action.class

```
public enum Action {

    @SerializedName("create") CREATE,
    @SerializedName("read") READ;

}
```

Trying to serialize a `Hashtable` or another pojo that uses this Enum, I get the string in capital letters.

```
...
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder.create();
Hashtable<Action, String> table = new Hashtable<>();
table.put(Action.CREATE, "");
gson.toJson(table) // => { "CREATE" : "" } instead of { "create" : "" }
...
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What happens if you have a field whose value is an enum? (Also, `Hashtable` should almost never be used in new code; you probably want `HashMap`.)

Comment: Using the enum as a field of another class works. The serialization function turn the enum to lower case. Btw, I'm working on an existing code, hence changing the hashtable to hashmap may break some code, so I won't touch it right now.

Comment: So it sounds like there's a specific problem with using `@SerializedName` as map keys?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Lower case enum Gson](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29056676/lower-case-enum-gson)

Comment: Well it can't be duplication, because the answer written there doesn't work in my case...

Comment: @Candroid It suggests that `@SerializedName` isn't supported for `enum`s in Gson. As far as I understand how Gson works, this annotation can only work for fields on an object to be serialized or deserialized -- `enum`s are just not that case.

Comment: :/ so what do you suggest me to do? Create a serializer?

Comment: @Candroid Yep, it's not a duplicate, you're right for the "duplication" and @chrylis is right about the reason. `@SerializedName` can work with objects only, but it cannot work with `Map`s or `Hashtable`s. You have either to create your custom type adapter for such cases (that would be pretty much a copy of `MapTypeAdapterFactory` with `enum`+`@SerializedName` keys and values analyzer -- and Gson does not do it I think with a good rationale behind it), or to get rid of maps or hashtables and use data transfer objects that would be `@SerializedName`-friendly. I would suggest you option #2.

Comment: `enum`+`@SerializedName` work fine if they are used in the scope of `ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory` ((de)serializing POJOs). But `@SerializedName` for `enum`s would appear as a value of a JSON object, not a key, as far as I understand.

Comment: I have opened an issue in gson GitHub project. I think I'll break conventions and just name those enum fields with lower case values.

Answer (score 4):

Your code works as expected when you add the `enableComplexMapKeySerialization` option to your Gson instance.

https://google.github.io/gson/apidocs/com/google/gson/GsonBuilder.html#enableComplexMapKeySerialization--

`Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().enableComplexMapKeySerialization().create();`

Answer (score 2):

Apart of the comments to your question (that `MapTypeAdapterFactory` is not `@SerializedName`-aware) that explain why it does not work for maps and suggest to change your data exchange model if possible, you can use a custom `JsonSerializer` if you really mush use data bags like `Map` or `Hashtable`:

```java
private static final TypeToken<?> actionToUnknownHashtableTypeToken = new TypeToken<Hashtable<Action, ?>>() {
};
```

Note that the type token is used to target the serializable enum more precisely and cache the internal serialized names mapping:

```java
final Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
        .registerTypeAdapter(actionToUnknownHashtableTypeToken.getType(), getSerializedNameEnumHashtableJsonSerializer(Action.class))
        .create();
final Hashtable<Action, String> table = new Hashtable<>();
table.put(CREATE, "item");
out.println(gson.toJson(table, actionToUnknownHashtableTypeToken.getType()));
```

Also note the `toJson` method use. Thus each certain enum you'd make `@SerializedName`-aware could be registered separately. And the serializer itself:

```java
final class SerializedNameEnumHashtableJsonSerializer<K extends Enum<K>, V>
        implements JsonSerializer<Hashtable<K, V>> {

    private final Map<K, String> serializedNames;

    private SerializedNameEnumHashtableJsonSerializer(final Map<K, String> serializedNames) {
        this.serializedNames = serializedNames;
    }

    static <K extends Enum<K>, V> JsonSerializer<Hashtable<K, V>> getSerializedNameEnumHashtableJsonSerializer(final Class<K> enumClass) {
        try {
            final Map<K, String> serializedNames = new HashMap<>();
            for ( final K enumConstant : enumClass.getEnumConstants() ) {
                final String enumName = enumConstant.name();
                final Field field = enumClass.getField(enumName);
                final SerializedName serializedName = field.getAnnotation(SerializedName.class);
                if ( serializedName != null ) {
                    serializedNames.put(enumConstant, serializedName.value());
                }
            }
            return new SerializedNameEnumHashtableJsonSerializer<>(unmodifiableMap(serializedNames));
        } catch ( final NoSuchFieldException ex ) {
            throw new AssertionError(ex);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public JsonElement serialize(final Hashtable<K, V> hashtable, final Type type, final JsonSerializationContext context) {
        final JsonObject jsonObject = new JsonObject();
        for ( final Entry<K, V> e : hashtable.entrySet() ) {
            final K key = e.getKey();
            final String nameCandidate = serializedNames.get(key);
            final String serializedName = nameCandidate != null ? nameCandidate : key.name();
            jsonObject.add(serializedName, context.serialize(e.getValue()));
        }
        return jsonObject;
    }

}
```

Also note that the serializer above only processes `SerializedName.value`, and does not care for `SerializedName.alternate`. The output:

> {"create":"item"}

Note that this works for keys only, and does not affect `@SerializedName` that may appear for enums that are values in serialized maps. The example above can also be reworked to process any enum automatically and not require each such a map or hashtable to be registered in `GsonBuilder`s (having to re-analyze `@SerializedName` annotations in every `serialize` method probably using a caching mechanism), but it would some design choice for you.